# Artery flow. What is the rate of change when $h = 0.3cm$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is known that the arteries the thicker the fat layer, the smaller the
cross section for
blood. Assume that the radius of the cross section
of an artery(cylindrical) is $0.9cm$. If the pattern that follows the fat when accumulating is of a band
circulate around the arterial wall whose thickness is $h$, then the area, $A$, of the
transverse section decreases with increasing $h$. What is the rate of change when $h = 0.3cm$?

Well, I don´t know if my equations are correct.

We got for the speed of the blood:  $v(h) = R^2 - h^2$ but I don´t feel like this is correct, because if I substitute $R=0.9$ and $h=0.3$, I end up with a constant which isn´t derivable. Any hints?

Comment: Is the question asking the rate of change of area?

Comment: And also could you explain how you got the equation for the speed of blood?

Comment: I don´t know for sure but I´m assuming that is asking for the rate of change of blood circulation. And for the question maybe is better the  Poiseuille equation: $Q=π(R-h)^4$ but I feel like is the same problem.

Comment: The question, I believe, is asking about the rate of change of area with respect to $h$, the width of the fat layer. At any instant, $A=\pi(0.9-h)^2$. Differentiate this and set $h=0.3$ and you’ll be done.